# Download file on React js passed as byte array

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

In the DB I am storing and image and a file in a byte array. From a request (written in .Net core) I retrieve the byte array to the front end (written in react js). I can display the image using

```
let image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + byteArray;
```

and it works fine. I want to do the same thing with a file and when clicked just to download the file or open it in a new tab. The file is mainly PDF,word,excel. I have tried two things but they don't seem to work.

```
let uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(file);
window.open(uriContent, "document");
```

Is there some kind of different string that I need to concatenate before the byte array or am I using blob incorrectly?

```
let blob = new Blob(new Uint8Array(byteArray));
let file = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Ideally after this conversion I would be able to pass the file in an anchor tag

```
<a href={this.props.file}>Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try, While converting to the blob give the type as your file type like PDF or whatever your file type is, Then create object url and open in new window with window.open. 
In below code I am trying to download same file which you will select with file tag in download function.

```
<input type="file" onChange="Upload(this)"></input>
<script>
  function Upload(element) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = element.files[0];
    reader.onload = function () {
      var arrayBuffer = this.result;
      Download(arrayBuffer, file.type);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  function Download(arrayBuffer, type) {
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: type });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would just like to add this link, I think it's very useful https://medium.com/@riccardopolacci/download-file-in-javascript-from-bytea-6a0c5bb3bbdb

Answer (score 1):

Based on Atul's answer. This works to download a pdf file in ReactJs.

```html
const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: "application/pdf;charset=utf-8" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```